# How can I convert x^2 to x*x?

Tags: pattern-matching, algebraic-manipulation

When I try the following code:

```
a b^2 c /. b c -> e
```

*Mathematica* gives me:

> ```
> a b^2 c
> ```

but what I want is:

> ```
> a b e
> ```

The `FullForm` of `a b^2 c` is `Times[a, Power[b, 2], c]`, so it can not match the pattern `b c`.

the problem above is a simplified version of my practical one as below:

---

The practical problem which comes to me is:

```
dat = {Subscript[n, c] Subscript[n, d] Subscript[v, c] Subscript[v, d],Subscript[n, d] Subscript[p, c] Subscript[v, c] Subscript[v, d],I Subscript[h, d] Subscript[n, d] Subscript[p, d] Subscript[v, d],I Subscript[h, d] Subsuperscript[n, d, 2] Subscript[v, d],Subscript[n, c] Subscript[p, d] Subscript[v, c] Subscript[v, d],Subscript[p, c] Subscript[p, d] Subscript[v, c] Subscript[v, d],I Subscript[h, d] Subsuperscript[p, d, 2] Subscript[v, d],I Subscript[h, d] Subscript[n, d] Subscript[p, d] Subscript[v, d],I Subscript[h, c] Subscript[n, c] Subscript[p, c] Subscript[v, c],I Subscript[h, c] Subsuperscript[p, c, 2] Subscript[v, c],-Subscript[h, c] Subscript[h, d] Subscript[p, c] Subscript[p, d],-Subscript[h, c] Subscript[h, d] Subscript[n, d] Subscript[p, c],I Subscript[h, c] Subsuperscript[n, c, 2] Subscript[v, c],I Subscript[h, c] Subscript[n, c] Subscript[p, c] Subscript[v, c],-Subscript[h, c] Subscript[h, d] Subscript[n, c] Subscript[p, d],-Subscript[h, c] Subscript[h, d] Subscript[n, c] Subscript[n, d]}

rules = {Subscript[h, c] Subscript[p, c]->I Subscript[h, e] Subscript[n, e]+Subscript[h, f] Subscript[p, f],Subscript[h, c] Subscript[n, c]->Subscript[h, f] Subscript[n, f]+I Subscript[h, e] Subscript[p, e],Subscript[p, c] Subscript[v, c]->I Subscript[n, e] Subscript[v, e]+Subscript[p, f] Subscript[v, f],Subscript[n, c] Subscript[v, c]->I Subscript[p, e] Subscript[v, e]+Subscript[n, f] Subscript[v, f],Subscript[h, d] Subscript[p, d]->I Subscript[h, f] Subscript[n, f]+Subscript[h, e] Subscript[p, e],Subscript[h, d] Subscript[n, d]->Subscript[h, e] Subscript[n, e]+I Subscript[h, f] Subscript[p, f],Subscript[p, d] Subscript[v, d]->Subscript[p, e] Subscript[v, e]+I Subscript[n, f] Subscript[v, f],Subscript[n, d] Subscript[v, d]->Subscript[n, e] Subscript[v, e]+I Subscript[p, f] Subscript[v, f]}

dat//.rules
```

some elements of the `dat` can't be matched by `rules` and `ReplaceRepeated`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sure you need to transform x^2 into x*x to achieve your goal? A simpler thing will work with the same result:

```
a b^2 c /. b^2 c -> b e
```

> a b e

In cases like this you can always find correct algebraic form to replace, so the substitution will just work without any tricks. Of course you always can do something like

```
x^2 /. x^2 -> Defer[x x]
```

> x x

but you maybe over-thinking it.

Comment: But I have a similar question that maybe not solved by this method suitably. The question is pasted following the first one.

Answer (score 5):

In the example you gave, `Simplify` works

```
In[1]:=  Simplify[a b ^ 2 c, b c == e]
Out[1]:= a b e
```

Recall that `Simplify[expr,assum]` "does simplification using assumptions".

Comment: if I try `Simplify[a b^2 c, b c == e f g]`,I get `a b^2 c`.

Comment: the `Simplify` can't instead of `->` in some cases.

Comment: I reckon `Simplify[a b^2 c, b c == e f g]` gives `a b^2 c` because it's considered shorter than `a b e f g`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
a b^2 c /. c -> e/b
(*
==> a b e
*)
```

Generally it is a good idea to try to replace only a single symbol and let algebra do the rest.

Another possibility is to use separate rules for powers, like this:

```
powerreplace[x_ y_, z_] :=
  Sequence[x y -> z,
           x^n_ y -> x^(n-1) z,
           x y^m_ -> y^(m-1) z,
           x^n_ y^m_ -> x^(n-1) y^(m-1) z]

a b^2 c /. { powerreplace[b c, e] }
(*
==> a b e
*)
```

Note that here the list around `powerreplace` is mandatory (I didn't put it right into `powerreplace` to allow more easy use in combination to other rules, like

```
a b^2 c d //. { powerreplace[a b, x], powerreplace[b c, y], d->z }
(*
==> x y z
*)
```